# Xquery extracting property values from .properties file

Tags: properties, xquery, marklogic, roxy

I am currently trying to extract property values from my properties file, but am running into some problems. I can't test this in ML query console, because the properties file doesn't exist there. I am currently trying to grab the values of the file like this

`let $port := #{@properties["ml.properties-name"]}`

I've also looked at

```
xdmp:document-get-properties(
   $uri as xs:string,
   $property as xs:QName
```

however that is limited to .xml files I believe. Does anyone have a way/work-around of accessing these values? I can't seem to find one I've looked at some documentation on Marklogic's website, but can't seem to get anything to work. The way I was accessing before was in ruby, through monkey-patching allowing me to access those private fields.The problem with that is the ruby script I call is only called once, while my .xqy file is ran every minute that sends args to another function. I need to access those args from the properties file, right now I just have them hard-coded in. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I flagged to be closed, I think it is to broad and I have found an approach that I implemented and it worked, but it doesn't fit the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access deployment properties like that, but you can pass them along with deployment. If you create a new REST app with latest Roxy, you should get a copy of this `config.xqy` added to `src/config/`:

https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/blob/master/deploy/sample/custom-config.xqy

That file is treated specially when deployed to the modules database. Properties references are replaced inside there. In your case, add another variable, and give it a string value following the `@ml.xyz` pattern:

```
declare variable $c:port := "@ml.property-name";
```

You can then import the config lib, and use it in your code.

These so-called Deployer Substitutions are described in more detail on the Roxy wiki:

https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/wiki/Deployer-Substitutions